# Ocultar registros en query que cumplan una condición, que el siguiente registró no tenga un campo específico igual

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sql

He realizado una query muy sencilla y me da estos datos:

```
select * from personas ORDER BY CAST(checkm.orden as integer)
```

y me devuelve (ojo muy importante que este en orden según el campo ORDEN)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven el campo tipo esta compuesto de 0  y 1

intento evitar que el resultado exista VALORES consecutivos igual a 1 en el campo TIPO

Intento buscar esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo busco resultados que tengan esta condición:

```
registro 1.... tiene tipo 1(OK)
registro 2.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
registro 3.... tiene tipo 1(OK)
registro 4.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
registro 5.... tiene tipo 1(OK)
registro 6.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
registro 7.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
registro 8.... tiene tipo 1(OK)
registro 9.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
registro 10.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
registro 11.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
registro 12.... tiene tipo 1(NO)  PORQUE EXISTE UN REGISTRO CON TIPO = 1 DESPUÉS
registro 13.... tiene tipo 1(NO)  PORQUE EXISTE UN REGISTRO CON TIPO = 1 DESPUÉS
registro 14.... tiene tipo 1(OK)
registro 15.... tiene tipo 0(OK)
```

Tengan en cuenta que la lista está en orden numérico por el campo ORDEN.

Comment: El título de la pregunta: ***ocultar registros** en query con un campo repetido*  y el planteamiento: *intento evitar que en el resultando existan **valores consecutivos igual a 1** en el campo `tipo`...* son **contradictorios**. La esperanza de entender lo que quieres queda truncada como la imagen misma que compartes. Así que no queda clara la pregunta. ¿Quieres ocultar registros? ¿Bajo qué criterios? ¿O simplemente quieres cambiar el orden de los mismos, alternando entre `1` y `0`?

Comment: Hola gracias. acabo de modificar la pregunta. mi idea solo ocultar los registros que tienen TIPO = 1 solo si después de ellos existe otro registro con tipo = 1 o no exista otro registro... en caso contrario mostrarlo.

Comment: Ahora se entiende mejor. Pero hace falta que digas claramente si los registros deben estar organizados por alguna columna. En la consulta parece que quieres que estén organizados por la columna `orden`.

Comment: Listo .. muchas gracias.. tendrás alguna idea .. de como poder hacerlo.

Comment: Como siempre digo, tratar de solucionar problemas de vista con una query no es algo para lo que este hecho SQL... En sql se procesan los registros de a 1.. no viendo su entorno, ya que no existe entorno de registros en SQL (no hay anterior y posterior para la DB). Por lo tanto, que estas necesitando que no implique una consulta SQL? (con un SP se puede resolver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola talvez puedas utilizar la función de agregación LAG() para retornar el elemento de la fila que está antes de la fila actual. Para ilustrar la propuesta fijate en las flechas de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después suma el valor tipo con el valor de LAG() si el resultado es 2 lo filtras con el WHERE. A continuacion relaciono como quedaria el query:

```
--sql server
with cte AS (
    SELECT 
        orden
        ,id
        ,valor
        ,denom
        ,tipo
        ,(LAG(tipo) OVER (ORDER BY orden)) AS lag
        ,(LAG(tipo) OVER (ORDER BY orden))+tipo AS [lag+tipo]
    FROM test.dbo.ocultaregistros
    )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE [lag+tipo] < 2;


--oracle 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        orden
        ,id
        ,valor
        ,denom
        ,tipo
        ,(LAG(tipo) OVER (ORDER BY orden)) AS lag
        ,(LAG(tipo) OVER (ORDER BY orden))+tipo AS [lag+tipo]
    FROM test.dbo.ocultaregistros
    )
WHERE [lag+tipo] < 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

No conozco con mucha profundidad MySQL, por lo que te voy a plantear una solución más genérica de SQL. En primer lugar creamos un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo (
  Orden INT,
  Tipo  INT
);

INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Orden, Tipo) 
VALUES (1,0), (2,1), (3,0), (4,0), (5,1), (6,1), (7,0);

SELECT * FROM Ejemplo;
```

Te darás cuenta que si bien la estructura no se parece a la tuya, si tenemos las dos columnas que vamos a necesitar `Orden`, que va a ser nuestro `ID` y `Tipo` que es la columna que vamos a comparar. Los datos serían:

```
| Orden | Tipo |
|-------|------|
|     1 |    0 |
|     2 |    1 |
|     3 |    0 |
|     4 |    0 |
|     5 |    1 |
|     6 |    1 |
|     7 |    0 |
```

Lo primero que vamos a hacer es generar una nueva columna con el `Orden` del registro anterior:

```
SELECT E.Orden,
       E.Tipo,
       MAX(E1.Orden) AS 'OrdenAnterior'
    FROM Ejemplo E
    LEFT JOIN Ejemplo E1
       ON E1.Orden < E.Orden
    GROUP BY E.Orden,
             E.Tipo
    ORDER BY E.Orden
```

**Resultado**: Como vemos cada fila tiene en `OrdenAnterior` el valor del `Orden` de la fila anterior

```
| Orden | Tipo | OrdenAnterior |
|-------|------|---------------|
|     1 |    0 |        (null) |
|     2 |    1 |             1 |
|     3 |    0 |             2 |
|     4 |    0 |             3 |
|     5 |    1 |             4 |
|     6 |    1 |             5 |
|     7 |    0 |             6 |
```

Con este resultado solo tenemos que agregar un nuevo `JOIN` para verificar el campo `Tipo` si el actual es `1` y el anterior también lo es no retornamos esa fila

```
SELECT E2.Orden, 
   E2.Tipo
   FROM (SELECT E.Orden,
             E.Tipo,
             MAX(E1.Orden) AS 'OrdenAnterior'
          FROM Ejemplo E
          LEFT JOIN Ejemplo E1
             ON E1.Orden < E.Orden
          GROUP BY E.Orden,
                   E.Tipo
          ORDER BY E.Orden
   ) E2
LEFT JOIN Ejemplo E3
  ON E3.Orden = E2.OrdenAnterior
  WHERE NOT (E3.Tipo = 1 AND E2.Tipo = 1 AND E3.Tipo IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY E2.Orden;
```

**Salida final**:

```
| Orden | Tipo |
|-------|------|
|     1 |    0 |
|     2 |    1 |
|     3 |    0 |
|     4 |    0 |
|     5 |    1 |
|     7 |    0 |
```

**[Ver demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf899d/3)**

Comment: Muchas gracias. he realizado los pasos pero la query tarda demasiado en cargar. la explicación realiza lo que busco pero tarde demasiado.

Comment: Seguramente por que la columna `Orden` no está indexada. Saludos.

Comment: agregue el indece al campo orden y aun demora mucho la query.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu problema, para encontrar el resultado hay que realizar una consulta que cumpla con las siguientes condiciones:

- Mostrar todas las entradas que tengan TIPO = 0
- Mostrar todas las entradas que tengan TIPO = 1 y la siguiente entrada sea de TIPO = 0 (ordenadas por columna ORDEN).

La siguiente consulta cumple con las 2 condiciones:

```
SELECT * FROM personas p1 
WHERE p1.Tipo = 0 OR
(p1.Tipo = 1 AND p1.Tipo <> 
 (SELECT p2.Tipo
 FROM personas p2
 WHERE p2.ORDEN > p1.ORDEN
 ORDER BY CAST(checkm.orden as integer)
 LIMIT 1))
ORDER BY CAST(checkm.orden as integer)
```

En el WHERE es donde se especifican las 2 condiciones:

- `p1.Tipo = 0` - Estamos diciendo que se permitan todas las entradas con TIPO = 0
- `p1.Tipo = 1 AND p1.Tipo <> ()` - Estamos diciendo que se permitan todas las entradas que sean de TIPO = 1 y que la siguiente entrada (ordenada por ORDEN) sea de TIPO diferente (Es decir, TIPO = 0)

El SELECT anidado devuelve una única entrada (LIMIT 1) cuyo ORDEN es el siguiente al actual.